# cannot access hidden LXDE panel

Tags: gui, raspbian, lxde

Thinking that CPU and RAM information would clutter the primary default panel, I decided to create a separate side panel to display it optionally. I then set the panel to hide at 0 pixels and can no longer access it.

Does the panel still have a config file somewhere so I can change the settings without being able to unhide it?

I know I can just make a new panel and not bother with the useless properties file collecting dust in some directory somewhere..

Comment: LXDE is the default [desktop environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) used on raspbian. If you can't get an answer here, you might try LXDE's own forum: http://forum.lxde.org/

Answer (score 2):

The config files for lxpanels should be found in the directory `/home/uesr/.config/lxpanel/LXDE/panels/`.

It looks something like the example below and should be pretty straightforward. To reload the config after editing, you must first kill lxpanel:
`killall lxpanel`

You'll notice the panels disappear and then you can start it with the new config with something like this (Note the trailing ampersand which will run this process in the background):

`lxpanel --profile LXDE &`

I say "something like this" because in this case my profile is called LXDE. However, if you look in the directory `/home/user/.config/lxpanel/` you may see a few different directories. Each directory located in `/home/user/.config/lxpanel/` is a profile.

From `man lxpanel`:

```
FILES
       ~/.config/lxpanel/PROFILE
           config file, can be edited by preference dialog.
```

For me, the output of `ls /home/user/.config/lxpanel/` displays the following profiles(directories): `default  Lubuntu  LXDE`. Mine are in LXDE so I use `lxpanel --profile LXDE &` to run lxpanel.

Below is an example of a panel I have that just displays the clock plugin at the right side of the screen. The config file itself is `/home/user/.config/lxpanel/LXDE/panels/left` which is misleading since it's located on the right. Depending on how you created the panel, the name may not indicate the actual location of the panel so make sure you are working in the correct config file.

```
# lxpanel <profile> config file. Manually editing is not recommended.
# Use preference dialog in lxpanel to adjust config when you can.

Global {
    edge=right
    allign=center
    margin=31
    widthtype=pixel
    width=36
    height=52
    transparent=0
    tintcolor=#e6eeed
    alpha=185
    autohide=1
    heightwhenhidden=2
    setdocktype=1
    setpartialstrut=0
    usefontcolor=0
    fontsize=10
    fontcolor=#000000
    usefontsize=0
    background=1
    backgroundfile=/usr/share/lxpanel/images/background.png
    iconsize=24
    loglevel=2
}

Plugin {
    type = dclock
    Config {
        ClockFmt=%I:%M
        TooltipFmt=%A %x
        BoldFont=0
        IconOnly=0
        CenterText=0
    }
}

Plugin {
    type = dclock
    Config {
        ClockFmt=%R
        TooltipFmt=%A %x
        BoldFont=0
        IconOnly=0
        CenterText=0
    }
}
```